# The builder launch configuration could not be found

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

When I try to export an apk of my Android application I get this error :

```
Export Wizard Error   
   Errors occurred during the build

Problems occured when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.resources".
   The builder launch configuration could not be found
   The builder launch configuration could not be found
```

The error is really strange, because I can run/debug the application with the emulator or a device. Is there something to do to prevent this error ?

Tkx

Answer (score 85, accepted):

1.Select the right project
2.Choose "project"on the tool bar -> Properties
3.Click "Builders" in the menus of the popped up window
4.Remove the missing builders

Comment: I also had to check all dependent library projects to see if they had missing builders as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you have not checked Is Library.

Just go to Rightclick on your project -> Properties -> Android -> Checked Is Library

because you want to use external library in your project and Is Library give you chance to bind library to your project so you have not checked this library so therefore project could not find the external Library.

Thank you marked m if really help this answer